# Recover an old version file from HDD

Tags: data-recovery

An Excel file replaced with an old version. Is it possible to restore old version?

I tried to use Windows System Restore, but nothing happened!

`a.xls (8kb)` from Desktop replaced `a.xsl (120kb)` on `D:\`.

I need to recover `D:\a.xsl`.

Comment: The importance of a good back-up strategy...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Windows System Restore is for recovering your system to an early state in time - not individual files which remain untouched by this.

You may have some luck right clicking on the drive, and then choosing `Properties`, then go to the `Previous Versions` tab and click open.

[image]

From here, you should be able to browse previous versions of files.

It doesn't always work, but when it does it is great.

You can also right click and do this on individual files to see them at a certain point in time.

If however you moved/copied the file, then you have to do this on the drive or folder the file came from.

Comment: it's win xp and i can't see previous version tab! :|

Comment: I don't believe it exists in XP, only Win 7.